# Best approach for migrating Maven development projects into AWS Code Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

We are trying to migrate several of our Java/Maven projects into AWS Code Pipeline and we could not find a good and reasonable migration approach (our current architecture is to use AWS for production). Specifically we are interested in several things:

1. How to cache Maven dependencies so that build tasks do not download the same packages all over again.
   There are several approaches possible, for example:
   a) Use Code Artifact, but then the Maven projects will be connected to a specific AWS subscription.
   b) Use S3 buckets, but then 3PP modules (Maven Wagons) will need to be used.
   c) Use EC2 instance for building.
   d) Use Docker container created specifically for build purposes.
2. It is not really clear if Jenkins or Code Pipeline is recommended as a CI/CD product in AWS. We could see some examples that Code Pipeline is used with Jenkins. What is the purpose of such a setup.

Thank you,